# Which method is called when we go from Presented ViewController to Previous ViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a question I am working on an app in Which I presented a `ViewController(FilterVC)` from my previous `ViewController(ItemsVC)`. I stored filter data in my delegate method like this

```
protocol FilterVCDelegate: class {
func didSelectedFilters(_ sender: FilterVC, with selectedFilters: [String:Any])
}
```

and on button click I successfully passed the data to my previous `ItemVC` like this:-

```
@IBAction func applyButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    printD(selectedFilters)
    self.delegate?.didSelectedFilters(self, with: self.selectedFilters)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**ItemVC:-**

```
func didSelectedFilters(_ sender: FilterVC, with selectedFilters: [String : Any]) {
    self.currentFilters = selectedFilters
    printD("selectedFilters \(currentFilters)") // successfully get data from previous vc
}
```

and here is calling api method:-

```
func searchFromLatestRelease() {

  //  let param: [String:Any] = ["page": pageNo, "search_term": forSearch, "order_by": "date", "token": commonClass.sharedInstance.userToken ?? ""]

    let param: [String:Any] = ["price_range": currentFilters["price"] as? [String] as Any, "page": "0", "is_rating": currentFilters["Product Rating"] as? [String] as Any]
    printD("param: \(param)")
    Alamofire.request(Constants.API.url("search"), method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        guard let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else {return}
        printD(json)

        guard let status = json["status"] as? Int else {return}
        printD(status)

        if status == 1 {

            if self.pageNo == 0 { self.sneakers = [] }
            guard let data = json["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else { return}

            printD(data)
            for dic in data {
                self.sneakers.append(sneakerModel(response: dic))
            }

            self.reloadData()

        }
        else {
            commonClass.sharedInstance.showErrorMessage(json["msg"] as? String ?? "Server error. Please try again later.")
        }
    }
}
```

But it won't work In called it in `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewDidLoad`.
Now I need to use these filer as a parameter to call the **API**. to refresh the data and successfully show the filtered items on `ItemsVC`. There are 8 `ViewControllers` in ViewController LifeCycle but I don't which is to used to refresh my `ItemVC` to show the filtered data. Please help?

Here I am getting my currenFilter in console like this:-

```
selectedFilters ["Product Rating": ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"], "Price": ["$00.00 - $200.00", "$200.00 - $400.00", "$600.00 - $800.00", "$800.00 - $1000.00", "$1000.00 AND OVER"]]
```

(lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called once when the vc is initated , `ViewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` called after model dismiss , you need

```
func didSelectedFilters(_ selectedFilters: [String : Any]) {
    self.currentFilters = selectedFilters
    self.searchFromLatestRelease()
}
```

Comment: I think no need for **_ sender: FilterVC** parameter  as it's useless and should be deal located after the dismiss

Comment: Okay Sir I will remove this